# How can I get rid of a bounty and keep my stolen items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was screwing around in skyrim and accidently got caught lockpicking something. I have a habbit of stealing tons of stuff so if I pay bounty, or go to jail, I lose most of my stuff. The only way I've managed to get out of it so far is to either pay 100 gold or so because I'm a member of the Thieves Guild, or resist arrest and escape the city. Is there a way, like in oblivion, where you can pay someone to get rid of the bounty for you, where I could keep my stolen items?

Answer (score 26):

In Whiterun, I had a small bounty (5). Once I was bestowed a title by the Jarl for killing a dragon, I was able to flaunt my title to a guard to get him to waive my bounty.

You can get a perk in speech that allows you to bribe guards so you don't have your goods taken from you.

You can also go to the guard barracks of whatever town you're in and in the basement is a chest with your stolen stuff in it.

You can also buy a house and stash it there or give all your stolen stuff to a follower then go to jail.

Comment: You only get to play the thane card once per hold, though. If you've helped the thieves guild establish a presence in the hold in question, you will be able to pay half your bounty to a guard and have it cleared up.

Answer (score 4):

If you are playing on the PC, you can use console commands to "pay" your bounty while keeping your stolen items.

Make a save game first, and then in the game, open up the [console](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) by pressing <kbd>~</kbd>, then click on one of the arresting/assaulting guard(s). The guard's [RefID](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Console_IDs) should show up in the screen. After that, type in `paycrimegold` in the console. That should put you just outside the nearest jail of the hold you're in, with no more bounty on you while still keeping your stolen items.

[More info on the `paycrimegold` console command at the UESP wiki's "Console" article.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#paycrimegold)

> **paycrimegold** - Pay the bounty for the faction targeted NPC belongs to (the bounty gold will be removed from your inventory). The first 0-1 choice refers to being sent to jail: entering 1 will let you be teleported to the respective faction's jail, entering 0 won't. The second 0-1 choice refers to keeping your stolen items: entering 0 means you do not lose your stolen items, entering 1 means you do. If you don't add any choice you will be sent to jail without losing your stolen items. The faction ID is needed if you can't target an NPC. May also help in case guards attack you on sight.

If you don't have enough gold, you can also use the console to add gold to your character. The console command to do that is `player.additem f x` where `x` is the amound of gold you would like to add. With these commands, you could essentially "pay" your bounty without losing any gold.

Comment: Almost feels cheaterish, but very convenient!

Answer (score 3):

You can kill all the guards. I do it all the time.

Comment: While this method allows you to keep your stolen loot, it fails to meet the criteria of "get rid of bounty".  In fact it is likely to increase the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Just put every item you stole in a chest you own and keep it there. Remember not to put it in a chest you dont own. The owners most likely will steal your stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I just dropped my stuff on the ground behind a house and then paid my bounty after approaching a guard

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna keep your stolen items what you do is you go to the "sleeping giant inn" at river wood then you simply put all of your items in a chest in one of the rooms. After go to whiterun then punch a guard then put away your fists by clicking X or square wether if you have a ps3 or an Xbox. The guard will ask if you want to submit to jail say yes when you arrive in the jail sleep on the cot in the cell then when your jail time is over go back to river wood and get your items out the chest but do it quick

Comment: This just repeats what other answers have already said.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way to do that is to run away first so your not caught, find a follower and dump it all on them, when your done, tell then to wait, goto jail or pay off bounty then come back and get your items.

If your follower cant carry anymore do a glitch by dropping the items on the ground, tell them to do something and say to pick up the item/s.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you have a large bounty, a bounty collector will come to find you. You'll have to ask what he wants and he'll offer to pay your bounty, but for an extra price of 200 gold. But that means that you don't get your stolen items taken.

Answer (score 0):

Simple sell to a fence and then buy it back from them. The item won't be considered stolen after that so never have to worry about it again

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your house ( if you don't have one, I recommend the Solitude house if your a rich one and the Breeze home in Whiterun if your the cheap one) and take your stolen items and put it in your chests and that way its pretty safe so then you can go back to the cities that don't let you in or that have high bounties and talk to the guards or the guards will come to you.