# How do I get rid of a bounty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I am playing Skyrim Dragon-Born DLC on a PC. I have a bounty, but I can't hand myself in -- I just get attacked.  It stated that I attacked somebody at a shrine by accident, but after that I didn't commit any crimes.  It's weird how I get attacked instead of them talking to me. It seems like there is no way to get rid of the bounty.

I have tried on many occasions to hand myself into a different place from where I originally committed the crime.

Comment: Did you read [How can I get rid of a bounty and keep my stolen items?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35317/how-can-i-get-rid-of-a-bounty-and-keep-my-stolen-items)  I don't know this game, but that seems to be related.  Another one is [I have a huge bounty in Skyrim, how do I get rid of it?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38928/i-have-a-huge-bounty-in-skyrim-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)

Comment: no none of them work atm im still stuck

Comment: The answer at [Getting rid of 1000 plus bounty](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/45266/51171) is several paragraphs long.  If you've tried each method, then you should include what you tried and what happened in your question.  What happened when you sheathed your weapon?  What happened when you tried the Calm spell?  What happened when you punched an innocent person and kept your hands raised?  Was there a guard captain with the guards?  It also sounds like the title should change to "How do I surrender to the guards without being attacked?"

Comment: Yet another one:  [How to fix glitched bounty in Solstheim](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103713/how-to-fix-glitched-bounty-in-solstheim).  This has a longer discussion of how punching an innocent person works.